# liferay login portlet is not working in Apple i phone

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I have developed a portal in Liferay 6.2 and it is working fine in almost every condition except on an iphone. The login portlet in ios device is not working:  input fields in login portlet are disabled (we can't input anything in username and password input fields).

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Do you have a custom theme? This applies to browser-access, not a mobile app solution, right? Which *exact* version do you use? (GA x)... Also, please note [this article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and tag according to your question (e.g. you tagged liferay-7, but ask a question about Liferay 6.2).

Comment: Yeah i am using custom theme. And exact version is 6.2.

Comment: The exact version has three digits or a GA number. To make sure that this is not an issue with your custom theme please check with Liferay's default theme as well.

Comment: this is Liferay 6.2 GA-6 and  i will check the default theme and let you know as soon as possible.